# Selecting InfoWindow Text Causing Bad Scrolling

Tags: html, google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

I'm not sure if this is a Chrome or Google Maps API bug, but I'm observing odd behaviour when selecting text in an InfoWindow that has too much text to fix naturally (and so a vertical scroll bar is created). An example where this occurs comes right from the Google Maps API documentation:

- https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple-max

If your browser window small enough when visiting that map, clicking on the marker should create an info window with a vertical scroll bar. Selecting text near the top does not cause scrolling, but selecting text further down does when it really shouldn't. The type of scrolling is what I would expect if I was selecting text at the very bottom of the visible area (it would scroll down so more text could be selected). But the scrolling begins far too early.

It seems as though this is more pronounced when there is more text in the InfoWindow (requiring more vertical scrolling to see it all). The problem also arises when interacting with form elements (entering text in an input field or selecting a drop-down). Any suggestion as to how this can be fixed or where the problem may be? (i.e., is it a bug in Chrome or Google Maps API?)

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a Chrome bug. I'd file it over at http://crbug.com/

Comment: Thanks. Any reason specifically that leads you to think it's with chrome and not Google Maps?